# How to use a SOCK5 proxy resolving hostname with fsockopen in PHP?

Tags: php, proxy

I'm using this code to send a SMTP command to an email server, I would like to integrate a sock5 proxy inside my command fsockopen, how can I do this?

```
$mxSocket = @fsockopen($mxHost, 25, $errno, $errstr, 2);

if ($mxSocket) {

    $response = "";
    // say HELO to mailserver
    $response .= sendCommand($mxSocket, "EHLO mx1.validemail.com");
    // initialize sending mail
    $response .= sendCommand($mxSocket, "MAIL FROM:<info3@validemail.com>");
    // try recipient address, will return 250 when ok..
    $rcptText = sendCommand($mxSocket, "RCPT TO:<" . $emailRequest . ">");
    $response .= $rcptText;
    if (substr($rcptText, 0, 3) == "250") {

        return array('state' => true, 'content' => $response);
    
    }else {

        return array('state' => false, 'content' => $response);

    }
    // quit mail server connection
    sendCommand($mxSocket, "QUIT");
    fclose($mxSocket);


    //////////////////////////////
  
}else {

    return array('state' => false, 'content' => '');

}

function sendCommand($mxSocket, $command)
{

fwrite($mxSocket, $command . "\r\n");

$response = "";
stream_set_timeout($mxSocket, 1);

for the whole story.
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    while ($line = fgets($mxSocket)) {
      $response .= $line;
    }
    // Only continue the for-loop if the server hasn't sent anything yet.
    if ($response != "") {
      break;
    }
  }

//  print nl2br($response);
  return $response;
}
```

How can I use a Sock5 proxy to use in my PHP code same as I'm using with a CURL command?

Same as this command:

```
 curl -X -k --socks5-hostname xx.xx.x.xxx:5000 --proxy-user xxxx:xxxxx
```

Comment: add your sendcommand method

Comment: added on the post thanks